# How to query a blank date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

Is there a way in elasticsearch to query for a `date` type with a blank/empty value?  What value gets assigned in the index to blank date fields?

Must I use the `missing` filter, or is there a way to use a query - a `term` maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a null_value specified on the date field, I believe missing filter is the recommended way.

[This answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/S1-1L_MvA7c/11hoqP5fuioJ) in elasticsearch discussion group talks about value being null in query is treated similar to the value not present the way elasticsearch looks at it.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I went with and it seems to be working fine. `filter :missing, :field => 'last_attachment_at'` was the syntax that worked using the Tire gem.